# How to I make my insert statement in multiple lines?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to execute an insert query which is working when i write it in one line.

I want to separate in multiple lines to make my code readable
[This code isn't working when split into lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBONb.png)

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO dbo.SEGMENT_PROSPECTS([SEG_CATEGORY],[SEG_SUB_CATEGORY],[CUSTOMER_CNIC],
        [CUSTOMER_NAME],[CUSTOMER_MOBILE],[CUSTOMER_EMAIL],[CUSTOMER_GENDER],[CREATED_ON],[UPDATED_ON],[CREATED_BY],
        [UPDATED_BY]), values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', row['SEG_CATEGORY'],row['SEG_SUB_CATEGORY'],row['RELATIONSHIP_NUM'],
        row['MOBILE_PHONE'],row['PRIMARY_EMAIL'],row['FULL_NAME'],row['GENDER_CODE'],row['CREATED_ON'],row['UPDATED_ON'],row['CREATED_BY'],
        row['UPDATED_BY'])
```

Comment: The error says:
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: _Remove_ the comma right before `VALUES`.  It doesn't belong there.  Otherwise, your code looks find and should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data is a pandas dataframe? It'll be best to turn this into a dict and then pass values as a list.

Assuming you have more columns in your actual df, you can copy without changing/ removing it altogether.

```
new_row = row[['SEG_CATEGORY', 'SEG_SUB_CATEGORY', 'RELATIONSHIP_NUM', 'MOBILE_PHONE', 'PRIMARY_EMAIL', 'FULL_NAME', 'GENDER_CODE', 'CREATED_ON', 'UPDATED_ON', 'CREATED_BY', 'UPDATED_BY']].copy()

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO dbo.SEGMENT_PROSPECTS([SEG_CATEGORY],[SEG_SUB_CATEGORY],[CUSTOMER_CNIC],
        [CUSTOMER_NAME],[CUSTOMER_MOBILE],[CUSTOMER_EMAIL],[CUSTOMER_GENDER],[CREATED_ON],[UPDATED_ON],[CREATED_BY],
        [UPDATED_BY]), values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', new_row.values.tolist())
```